# Can I pass parameters into a function if I only have a pointer to a function in C?

Tags: c

I have a program, what it does isn't too important, I am mostly curious of the following:
If I have a struct that has pointers to a function, can I pass parameters into the function using that pointer? Here is part of my code

edit: I realized I was a little vague:
So is there anyway to use the variable 'x' of type funcs, to pass parameters into the my_closeit and my_openit using the pointer's initialized by x = {&openit, &closeit}; in the main function? By doing x -> or x. ?

Another Edit:
Would it be x.openit(some pointer, some int); ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int my_openit(char* name, int prot);
void my_closeit(void);

typedef struct funcs 
{
int (*openit)(char *name, int prot);
void (*closeit)(void);
}funcs;
//I know the first 'funcs' is unnecessary

int main()
{
funcs x = {&my_openit, &my_closeit};
return 0;
}

int my_openit(char* name, int prot)
{
return 0;
}

void my_closeit(void)
{
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do - I didn't understand?

Comment: The requirement of providing arguments to a function expecting said-same is the same, whether invoked through a pointer-to-function, or via the function id directly. a rose by any other name. You never actually put any *invoke* of the function pointers you demonstrated in your question, so your example is at-best half what it should be. I assume you want to invoke `x.openit`, and obviously, yes, just as if you were invoking `my_openit`, arguments *are* required.

Comment: "By doing x -> or x. ?". If `x` is  a pointer, use -> and if not, use dot(.). Simple.

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://onlinegdb.com/eOwj0iRgv)? You obviously cannot pass parameters to the other function, because it's not accepting any, but you can call it.

Comment: Calling a function through a pointer is actually the only way to do it. When you write a function call with the name of a function, the compiler actually automatically converts it to a pointer to the function for you. E.g., try `(*printf)(…)` instead of plain `printf`. The compiler automatically converts `printf` to a pointer, and then `*printf` converts it back to a function designator, but the compiler automatically converts that to a pointer. You can do it again and again: `(**************printf)(…)`. In the end, the compiler wins, and it is a pointer that is used.

Comment: So you could just give in to the compiler and write it as an address: `(&printf)(…)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I pass parameters into the function using that pointer?

Yes, obviously, or it wouldn't be of any use. In your case:

```
int result = x.openit("something", 123);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use function call expression through the pointers:

```
int r = x.openit("myfile",0);
x.closeit();
```